# How to get array value using coordinates in other array?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm looking to access an array using coordinates from a different array, like such. This for a situation where I don't on forehand know the number of dimensions in the data array, so can't really just use an undetermined number of optional variables in a function.

```
Dim myArray(1 To 4, 1 To 2) As String
Dim myCoord(1 To 2) As Long

myArray(1, 1) = "one_one"
myArray(1, 2) = "one_two"
...
myArray(4, 2) = "four_two"

myCoord(1) = 3
myCoord(2) = 1

MsgBox(myArray(myCoord))
```

So I'm looking for something like the above messagebox being able to display "three_one". Like in python's `my_multidim_list[*[i, j, ..., n]]` No idea if it's at all possible in VBA, but well, doesn't seem illogical to me to implement such a possibility.

Comment: I don't understand how you'd get coordinates from the second array, it's a one-dimensional array.

Comment: @TimStack I don't either. In Python you can expand the list or tuple, but I was hoping something like that is also possible in VBA.

Comment: Use a two-dimensional array instead, like `myArray` is. Tony's solution would absolutely work but I don't see the use of the array if it's one-dimensional

Comment: @TimStack coordinates are always a 1-dimensional array with a length equal to the number of dimensions in the data array. For instance if you have a point in 3D space you can indicate it through x, y, and z values, i.e. a 1D array with length 3: (x, y, z). So to get any value at an N-dimensional array you'll need coordinates possibly supplied in a 1-dimensional array with n values.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't follow. "*3D space...i.e. 1D array*" so you use a one dimensional array for three dimensions? That means only one field for three values. If you need coordinates for an array with two or more fields, you could use another array with two fields as coordinates. [Ref.](https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-6d31adab9023a0542ed428728c55f833.webp)

Comment: @TimStack Earth could be defined as a 4D realm if you include time, however you only need need 4 values to define your position, for instance through (Lat, Lon, Alt, timestamp). So if you were unlucky enough to be at Times Square at last new year's eve, you could define your position as (40.45'32'', 73.59'06'', 12m, 2018-12-31T23:30:00Z-4) which would be a 1-dimensional array with 4 values, to indicate your position in a 4-dimensional realm.

Comment: True, but in the case of a 1D array you'd have to pass the position as one string (1D arrays only have one field, one value per item), which you'd later have to split with a common delimiter. In that case, why not use a 2D array with 4 fields, so you have 1 field for each variable? `arr(0,0) = Lat`, `arr(0,1) = Lon`, `arr(0,2) = Alt`, `arr(0,3) = time`

Comment: Just because an array is one-dimensional doesn't mean it only contains one value.
```Dim myArr(10) As Long``` is a 1D array containing 10 Longs.

Comment: One field. Each field has one value. How do you populate this one field? "1,3" could work, but this is a single string which, like I said, you'd have to split. Not to mention that for each x and y combination you'd need a new record. With a two dimensional array, you would need only 1 record for each x value. It's not ideal at all, this is why multi-dimensional arrays exist

Comment: I shouldn't say "Each field has one value", but rather "Each record..."

Comment: I have added a new answer in two parts.  Let me know what you think.

Comment: @TonyDallimore Wow, that is awesome! Sorry, indeed I got a bit sidetracked by other work and this just managed to slip my mind. My apologies. I'll look at it in-depth tonight!

Answer (score 1):

This was my original answer which provides some background on VBA arrays.  I will be expanding it to provide enough background to understand my second answer.

The simple answer is:

```
Dim myArray(1 To 4, 1 To 2) As String
Dim myCoord(1 To 2) As Long

myArray(1, 1) = "one_one"
myArray(1, 2) = "one_two"
...
myArray(4, 2) = "four_two"

myCoord(1) = 3
myCoord(2) = 1

MsgBox(myArray(myCoord(1), myCoord(2)))   ' This is the only change
```

This is based on each element of `myCoord` defining the element number of the corresponding dimension of `myArray`.

**Extra information about arrays**

When you write `Dim myArray(1 To 4, 1 To 2) As String`, the number of dimensions and the number of elements in each dimension are fixed until you rewrite this statement with different numbers.

If you write `Dim myArray() As String`, you are declaring the array but the number of dimensions and their bounds will be defined at run time.

Within your code you can write `ReDim myArray(a To b, c To d, e To f)` where a to f are integer expressions.  In most languages I know, the lower bound is defined by the language as 0 or perhaps 1.  With VBA, the lower bound can be anything providing the lower bound is not more than the upper bound.  I have only once found a use for a negative lower bound but the option is there.

Later you can write `ReDim myArray(g To h)` but you will lose all the data within myArray.

Alternatively, you can write `ReDim Preserve myArray(a To b, c To d, e To g)`.  Note that a to e are unchanged.  With `ReDim Preserve` only the upper bound of the last dimension can be changed.  `ReDim Preserve` creates a new larger (or smaller) array, copies data from the old array and initialises the new elements to the default value for the data type.  Over use of `ReDim Preserve` can slow your macro down to a crawl because the interpreter runs out of memory but if used carefully it can be very useful.

I would probably define `myCoords` with the same number of dimensions as `myArray` but that depends on your objective.

There is a lot more I could say about VBA arrays.  If you expand on your objectives I will add appropriate extra information.

Comment: Thanks for the input so far. I'm sorry but I can't use just myCoord(1), myCoord(2) because that would imply I already know the number of dimensions beforehand. Also, a select case system would be kinda inefficient as who knows, the array may be tens of dimensions large. :(

Comment: I'm currently looking at a "For Each" system with mod. It's extremely inefficient, but I will be able to fetch the specific value eventually...

Comment: I am assuming you have some outer code that defines myArray to the number of dimensions and the number of elements required for today's problem,  If myArray is passed to a subroutine, that routine can identify the number of dimensions and the lower and upper bounds of each dimension.  myCoord can be dimensioned to match myArray.  A loop on the number of dimensions containing a loop on the bounds for each dimension would then be easy.

Comment: Yeah, the myArray is out of my immediate control, and indeed, it's no problem getting the structure of the array, nor to loop over the array until I've got the value I need, but if I just have that myArray, and a coordinate in a single array e.g. (3, 1), I'd prefer to be able to just take that coordinate and get that exact value from myArray without the inefficient loop. It shouldn't be that computer-intensive in my opinion. But I've been very flabbergasted too often with VB and VBA, so it wouldn't surprise me if looping through it is the only option.

Comment: Do you want `Function GetElement(ByRef myArray As String, ByRef myCoord As Long) as String` which returns the string from the element of myArray defined by MyCoord?

Comment: Something like that, yes! :)

Comment: @Stry  I am sure it is possible but I will have to think for a bit.

Comment: I also just found this question which is somewhat similar:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56078109/how-to-get-array-value-using-coordinates-in-other-array

Comment: @Stry  Your comment links to your own question.

Comment: I have thought of two methods of holding the strings that would give the effect you seek.  At the moment, I do not know which would be easiest to use or fastest or best for some other reason.  How would you load myArray?  My current thinking is that both the put and get operations need to be considered to get the best design.

Answer (score 0):

My answer has exceeded Stackoverflow's limit of 30,000 characters so I have split it into parts.  This is part 1.

Although you did not answer my question about how you intended to fill the array, I decided there was only one viable approach which I have implemented as a class.

If you had asked me a couple of months ago about VBA classes, I would have been dismissive.  My view was that if your requirement was complex enough to need a class, VBA was not an appropriate language.  I have not totally changed by mind but I recently discovered a VBA StringBuilder class which I found very convenient.  Building on that experience, I decided to create a class to address your requirement which showed me how easily a class can hide complex processing from the user.

I have named my class MultDimStrArray.  If you do not like this name, change it to something you prefer.  If you try my test macros, you will have change the name throughout their module.

My class has no public properties.  It has four public methods: `Initialise`, `PutElements`, `GetElements` and `OutDiag`.

`Initalise` records the number and bounds of the dimensions.  Example calls are:

```
Dim MyArray1 As New MultDimStrArray
Call MyArray1.Initialise("3 to 10", "2")
```

and

```
Dim MyArray2 As MultDimStrArray
Dim Bounds1 As Variant
Bounds1 = Array( ("3 to 10", "2") 
Call MyArray1.Initialise(Bounds1)
```

That is, you can create a multi-dimensional string array using:

```
Dim MyArray1 As New MultDimStrArray
```

or

```
Dim MyArray2 As MultDimStrArray
Set MyArray2 = New MultDimStrArray
```

The first method is more popular but apparently the second is more efficient.

You can record the bounds of the dimensions in the call of `Initialise` or in a predefined array.  I have used the function `Array` to load the array.  You can load an array in the conventional way if you prefer.  All three techniques are demonstrated in macro `Test1`

Once the MDS array has been initialised, you use `PutElements` to place values within it.  The format of the call is:

```
Call MyArray.PutElements(Start, Values)
```

Start is an array with one element per dimension in MyArray; it identifies an element within MyArray.  Values can be a single variable or an array of any type providing its elements can be converted to strings.  If Values is a single variable or an array of length one, its content will be copied to the element identified by Start.  If Values is an array of length greater than one, its contents are copied to MyArray starting at Start.  A call of `PutElements` can place a single value in MyArray or can fill the entire array or anything in between.  Macro `Test2` shows a variety of ways that `PutElements` can be used.

`GetElements` is used to extract a value or values from MyArray.  The format of the call is as for `PutElement` and the parameters are the same; only the direction of the copy is different.

The final method is `OutDiag` which has no parameters.  It output full details of MyArray to the Immediate Window.  The Immediate Window can hold up to about 200 rows.  I considered output to a text file.  If you need this routine and you have large volumes of data, I can amend it for file output.

I have tested the methods but not exhaustively.  I believe I have created something that will meet your needs.  However, I did not wish to spend more time testing it before confirming it does meet your needs particularly as your real data may different significantly from anything I might create.

Do not look at the class yet other than to look at the how-to-use documentation at the top of each method.  Try macros `Test1`, `Test2` and `Test3`.  Adapt them to better match your requirements.  Try some real data.  I have left my original answer at the end of this answer but you will need more background on VBA arrays to understand the code within the class.  I will expand my original answer as my next task.

This block of code is the class.  It must be placed in a Class Module named `MultDimStrArray`.  I have left my diagnostic code but have commented most of it out.  If you encounter errors, report them to me since I do not think you have the knowledge to debug the class yourself.

```
Option Explicit
' Members
Private MDSArray() As String  ' The MD array is held as a 1D array
' Elements are held in the sequence:
'  1D  2D  3D   4D ... nD
'  lb  lb  lb  lb      lb to ub
'  lb  lb  lb  lb+1    lb to ub
'  lb  lb  lb  lb+2    lb to ub
'   :   :   :   :      :
'  lb  lb  lb  ub      lb to ub
'  lb  lb lb+1 lb      lb to ub
'   :   :   :   :      :
'  ub  ub  ub  ub      lb to ub
' Note: each dimension has its own lower and upper bound
Private DimMax As Long        ' Number of dimensions
Private DimOffs() As Long     ' Offset from element to equivalent element in next
                              ' repeat for each dimension.
                              ' For dimension 1, this is offset from (a,b,c,d) to (a+1,b,c,d).
                              ' For dimension 2, this is offset from (a,b,c,d) to (a,b+1,c,d).
                              ' And so on.
                              ' Used to convert (a,b,c,d) to index into MDSArray.
Private InxMax As Long        ' The total number of elements in the MDS array
Private LBounds() As Long     ' Lower bound of each dimension
Private UBounds() As Long     ' Upper bound of each dimension
' Methods
Public Sub Class_Initialize()
  ' Will be called by interpreter when it wishes to initialise an instance of
  ' MultDimStrArray.  Setting NumDim = 0 indicates that the instance has not
  ' be initialised by the class.
  DimMax = 0
End Sub
Public Sub GetElements(ParamArray Params() As Variant)

  ' Extracts one or more strings starting at a specified element from
  ' the multi-dimensional string array.

  ' This sub has two compulsory parameters.  The declaration uses a ParamArray
  ' to allow maximum flexibility in the type of those parameters.  Effectively,
  ' this sub has a declaration of:
  '   GetElements(ByRef Start() As xxxx, ByRef Values() as yyyy) or
  '   GetElements(ByRef Start() As xxxx, ByVal Values as yyyy) or
  '     where xxxx can be any of the integer types plus Variant or String.
  '       and yyyy can be any type that can be accept a string.

  ' Start is a one-dimensional array with DimMax, integer elements.  If the
  ' type of the array is Variant or String, the element values must be integer
  ' or an integer held as a string. The bounds of the array are not important.
  ' A lower bound of one to match dimension one may be convenient but a lower
  ' bound of zero or some other value may be used if wished.

  ' If the MDS array has N dimensions, Start must contain N values each of
  ' which must be within the bounds for the corresponding dimension.  Together,
  ' the values within Start specify an element with the MDS array.

  ' Values can be a String or Varient variable or a one-dimensional String or
  ' Varient array.  If the values within the MDS array are known to be
  ' integer, real or Boolean, then other types.  However, if a value within
  ' the MDS array is not as expected, a call of GetElements may result in a
  ' fatal, VBA error.

  ' If Values is a variable or an array with a length of one, the value of
  ' element Start of the MDS array will be copied to Values.

  ' If Values is an array with a length greater than one, values will be
  ' copied to it from the MDS array starting from element Start. If possible,
  ' array Values will be filled; however, if there are insufficient elements
  ' in the MDS array, the remaining elements of Values will be left unchanged.

  'Debug.Print "GetElements"

  If DimMax = 0 Then
    Debug.Assert False    'Not initialised
    Exit Sub
  End If

  Dim InxA As Long
  Dim InxS As Long
  Dim InxV As Long
  Dim LB As Long
  Dim Start() As Long
  Dim UB As Long

  LB = LBound(Params)
  UB = UBound(Params)

  If LB + 1 <> UB Then
    Debug.Assert False  ' There must be exactly two parameters
    Exit Sub
  End If

  If VarType(Params(LB)) < vbArray Then
    Debug.Assert False  ' First parameter (Start) must be an array
    Exit Sub
  End If

  ' Params(Params(LB)) contains values for Start.
  InxS = 1
  If UBound(Params(LB)) - LBound(Params(LB)) + 1 <> DimMax Then
    Debug.Assert False  ' Start must have one entry per dimension
    Exit Sub
  End If

  ReDim Start(1 To DimMax)

  For InxV = LBound(Params(LB)) To UBound(Params(LB))
    ' An error here indicates a value that cannot be converted to a Long
    Start(InxS) = Params(LB)(InxV)
    If Start(InxS) < LBounds(InxS) Or Start(InxS) > UBounds(InxS) Then
      Debug.Assert False  ' Index is outside range for dimension
      Exit Sub
    End If
    InxS = InxS + 1
  Next

  InxA = 1
  For InxS = 1 To DimMax
    InxA = InxA + (Start(InxS) - LBounds(InxS)) * DimOffs(InxS)
  Next

  '' Report conversion from coordinates to InxA
  'Debug.Print "(";
  'For InxS = 1 To DimMax - 1
  '  Debug.Print Start(InxS) & ", ";
  'Next
  'Debug.Print Start(DimMax) & ") -> " & InxA

  If VarType(Params(UB)) < vbArray Then
    ' Single value to be extracted from element defined by Start
    'Debug.Assert False
    ' An error here indicates Params(UB) cannot hold the value in the MDS array
    Params(UB) = MDSArray(InxA)
  Else
    ' Array of values to be extracted starting at element defined by Start
    'Debug.Assert False
    'Debug.Print "Params(UB) Bounds: " & LBound(Params(UB)) & " To " & UBound(Params(UB))
    For InxV = LBound(Params(UB)) To UBound(Params(UB))
      Params(UB)(InxV) = MDSArray(InxA)
      'Debug.Print "(" & InxA & ") contains " & Params(UB)(InxV)
      InxA = InxA + 1
      If InxA > InxMax Then
        ' Have reached end of MDSArray
        Exit For
      End If
    Next
  End If

End Sub
Public Sub Initialise(ParamArray Params() As Variant)

  ' Initalises an instance of the class by:
  '   Setting DimMax to number of dimensions
  '   Recording lower and upper bounds in LBounds and UBounds
  '   Calculating length of each dimension and recording them in DimOffs
  '   Calculating total number of entries in array and recording in InxMax
  '   ReDimming MDSarray to the required length

  ' The format of the call is: Xxxx.Initialise(parameters)

  ' Xxxx must be an object of type MultDimStrArray which must have been
  ' defined in one of these two ways:

  '   (1) Dim Xxxx As New MultDimStrArray

  '   (2) Dim Xxxx As MultDimStrArray
  '       Set Xxxx = New MultDimStrArray

  ' Most people use method 1 although method 2 results in more efficient code
  ' according to Charles H Pearson.  http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx

  ' In all cases, the parameters are a list of bounds. Those bounds can be
  ' specified as a list in the Initialise call or can be preloaded into an
  ' array.

  ' If the bounds are specified within the call, its format will be something like:
  '   Call Xxxx.Initialise(BoundsForDim1, BoundsForDim2, BoundsForDim3, ...)

  ' If the bounds are specified in a preloaded array, its format will be something like:
  '     Bounds = Array(BoundsForDim1, BoundsForDim2, BoundsForDim3, ...)
  '     Call Xxxx.Initialise(Bounds)
  '   or
  '     Bounds(1) = BoundsForDim1
  '     Bounds(2) = BoundsForDim2
  '     Bounds(3) = BoundsForDim3
  '       :    :    :    :
  '     Call Xxxx.Initialise(Bounds)

  ' BoundsForDimN can be
  '     lb " to " ub
  '   or
  '     ub

  ' Each dimension will have its own lower bound (lb) and upper bound (ub).
  ' If the lb is not specified, it will default to 1. So 'ub' is equivalent to
  ' '1 To ub'

  'Debug.Print "Initalise"

  Dim Bounds() As String
  Dim BoundParts() As String
  Dim InxB As Long
  Dim InxP As Long
  Dim LB As Long
  Dim NumElmnts As Long

  ' Convert different formats for Params to a single format
  LB = LBound(Params)
  If LB = UBound(Params) Then
    ' Single parameter.
    'Debug.Assert False
    If VarType(Params(LB)) > vbArray Then
      ' Params(LB) is an array.  Call was of the form: .Initialise(Array)
      ' Copy contents of Array to Bounds
      'Debug.Assert False
      DimMax = UBound(Params(LB)) - LBound(Params(LB)) + 1
      ReDim Bounds(1 To DimMax)
      InxB = 1
      For InxP = LBound(Params(LB)) To UBound(Params(LB))
        ' If get error here, element InxP of Array could not be converted to a string
        Bounds(InxB) = Params(LB)(InxP)
        InxB = InxB + 1
      Next
    Else
      ' Params(LB) is not an array.  Call was of the form: .Initialise(X)
      ' where X is "N to M" or "M".  Using this class for a 1D array would
      ' be inefficient but the code would work so it is not forbidden.
      'Debug.Assert False
      DimMax = 1
      ReDim Bounds(1 To 1)
      ' If get error here,  X could not be converted to a string
      Bounds(1) = Params(LB)
    End If
  Else
    ' Multiple parameters.  Call was of the form: .Initialise(X, Y, Z ...)
      ' where X, Y, Z and so on can be "N to M" or "M".
      ' Copy X, Y, Z and so to Bounds
      'Debug.Assert False
      DimMax = UBound(Params) - LBound(Params) + 1
      ReDim Bounds(1 To DimMax)
      InxB = 1
      For InxP = LBound(Params) To UBound(Params)
        ' If get error here, one of X, Y, Z and so could not be
        ' converted to a string
        Bounds(InxB) = Params(InxP)
        InxB = InxB + 1
      Next
   End If

   'Debug.Print "Bounds in call:  ";
   'For InxB = 1 To UBound(Bounds)
   '  Debug.Print Bounds(InxB) & "  ";
   'Next
   'Debug.Print

   ' Decode values in Bounds and store in in LBounds and UBounds
   ReDim LBounds(1 To DimMax)
   ReDim UBounds(1 To DimMax)
   ReDim DimOffs(1 To DimMax)
   InxMax = 1

   For InxB = 1 To UBound(Bounds)
     ' Value can be "lb To Ub" or "Ub"
     If IsNumeric(Bounds(InxB)) Then
       ' Upper bound only
       'Debug.Assert False
       If Int(Bounds(InxB)) = Val(Bounds(InxB)) Then
         ' Integer value
         'Debug.Assert False
         LBounds(InxB) = 1
         UBounds(InxB) = Bounds(InxB)
       Else
         Debug.Print "Invalid parameter: " & Bounds(InxB)
         Debug.Assert False         ' Real ub; only integer indices allowed
         DimMax = 0                ' Not initialised
         Exit Sub
       End If
     Else
       ' lb To ub
       BoundParts = Split(LCase(Bounds(InxB)), " to ")
       LB = LBound(BoundParts)
       If LB + 1 <> UBound(BoundParts) Then
         Debug.Print "Invalid parameter: " & Bounds(InxB)
         Debug.Assert False         ' Not "ub" and not "lb to ub"
         DimMax = 0                ' Not initialised
         Exit Sub
       Else
         If IsNumeric(BoundParts(LB)) And _
            IsNumeric(BoundParts(LB + 1)) Then
           If Int(BoundParts(LB)) = Val(BoundParts(LB)) And _
              Int(BoundParts(LB + 1)) = Val(BoundParts(LB + 1)) Then
             'Debug.Assert False
             LBounds(InxB) = BoundParts(LB)
             UBounds(InxB) = BoundParts(LB + 1)
           Else
             Debug.Print "Invalid parameter: " & Bounds(InxB)
             Debug.Assert False         ' lb or ub or both are real; indices must be integer
             DimMax = 0                ' Not initialised
             Exit Sub
           End If
         Else
           Debug.Print "Invalid parameter: " & Bounds(InxB)
           Debug.Assert False         ' One or both of lb and ub are non-numeric or missing
           DimMax = 0                ' Not initialised
           Exit Sub
         End If
       End If
     End If
     If LBounds(InxB) > UBounds(InxB) Then
       Debug.Print "Invalid parameter: " & Bounds(InxB)
       Debug.Assert False         ' lb must be less than ub
       DimMax = 0                ' Not initialised
       Exit Sub
     End If
   Next InxB

   ' Calculate offset to equivalent element in next repeat for each dimension.
   DimOffs(DimMax) = 1
   NumElmnts = (UBounds(DimMax) - LBounds(DimMax) + 1)
   For InxB = DimMax - 1 To 1 Step -1
     DimOffs(InxB) = NumElmnts * DimOffs(InxB + 1)
     NumElmnts = (UBounds(InxB) - LBounds(InxB) + 1)  ' Need for next loop
   Next
   InxMax = NumElmnts * DimOffs(1)

   ReDim MDSArray(1 To InxMax)

End Sub
Public Sub OutDiag()

  Dim ColWidthCrnt As Long
  Dim ColWidthTotalLastDim As Long
  Dim ColWidthsLast() As Long
  Dim ColWidthsNotLast() As Long
  Dim Coords() As Long
  Dim InxA As Long            ' Index into MDSArray
  Dim InxC As Long            ' Index into Coords
  Dim InxD As Long            ' Index into dimensions
  'Dim InxL As Long            ' Index into Last dimension
  Dim InxWL As Long           ' Index into ColWidthsLast

  'Debug.Print "OutDiag"

  If DimMax = 0 Then
    Debug.Assert False   'Not initialised
    Exit Sub
  End If

  Debug.Print "DimMax=" & DimMax
  For InxD = 1 To DimMax
    Debug.Print "Dim" & InxD & "  Bounds=" & LBounds(InxD) & " to " & _
                UBounds(InxD) & "  Offset to next repeat=" & DimOffs(InxD)
  Next
  Debug.Print "InxMax=" & InxMax
  Debug.Print

  ReDim ColWidthsNotLast(1 To DimMax - 1)
  ReDim ColWidthsLast(LBounds(DimMax) To UBounds(DimMax))

  ' Ensure columns for all but last wide enough for headings and coordinates
  For InxD = 1 To DimMax - 1
    ColWidthsNotLast(InxD) = Len("D" & CStr(InxD))
    'Debug.Print "ColWidthsNotLast(" & InxD & ") initialsed to " & _
    '            ColWidthsNotLast(InxD) & " because of header ""D" & _
    '            CStr(InxD) & """"
    ColWidthCrnt = Len(CStr(LBounds(InxD)))
    If ColWidthsNotLast(InxD) < ColWidthCrnt Then
      Debug.Assert False
      ColWidthsNotLast(InxD) = ColWidthCrnt
      'Debug.Print "ColWidthsNotLast(" & InxD & ") increased to " & _
      '            ColWidthsNotLast(InxD) & " because of lower bound """ & _
      '            CStr(LBounds(InxD)) & """"
    End If
    ColWidthCrnt = Len(CStr(UBounds(InxD)))
    If ColWidthsNotLast(InxD) < ColWidthCrnt Then
      Debug.Assert False
      ColWidthsNotLast(InxD) = ColWidthCrnt
      'Debug.Print "ColWidthsNotLast(" & InxD & ") increased to " & _
      '            ColWidthsNotLast(InxD) & " because of upper bound """ & _
      '            CStr(UBounds(InxD)) & """"
    End If
  Next

  ' Ensure columns for last dimension wide enough for headings
  For InxWL = LBounds(DimMax) To UBounds(DimMax)
    ColWidthsLast(InxWL) = Len(CStr(InxD))
    'Debug.Print "ColWidthsLast(" & InxWL & ") initialised to " & _
    '            ColWidthsLast(InxWL) & " because of index """ & CStr(InxWL) & """"
  Next

  ' Ensure columns for last dimension wide enough for values
  ReDim Coords(1 To DimMax)
  ' Initialise Coords to indices for first entry in MDS array
  For InxC = 1 To DimMax
    Coords(InxC) = LBounds(InxC)
  Next

  '' Output co-ordinates to show which elements caused increase in width
  'Debug.Print "(";
  'For InxD = 1 To DimMax - 1
  '  Debug.Print Coords(InxD) & ", ";
  'Next
  'Debug.Print Coords(DimMax) & ") ";

  InxA = 1
  ' Check length of each value against length of each column for last dimension
  ' Increase length of column for last dimension if necessary
  Do While True
    ' Length for entry corrsponding specified by Coords
    ColWidthCrnt = Len(MDSArray(InxA))
    ' Column for current index into last dimension
    InxWL = Coords(DimMax)
    ' Increase column width if necessary
    If ColWidthsLast(InxWL) < ColWidthCrnt Then
      'Debug.Assert False
      ColWidthsLast(InxWL) = ColWidthCrnt

      '' Report reason for increased column width
      'Debug.Print "ColWidthsLast(" & InxWL & ") increased to " & _
      '            ColWidthsLast(InxWL) & " because of value """ & _
      '            MDSArray(InxA) & """"
    End If

    ' Step Coords to next entry
    For InxD = DimMax To 1 Step -1
      If Coords(InxD) < UBounds(InxD) Then
        Coords(InxD) = Coords(InxD) + 1
        Exit For
      Else
        Coords(InxD) = LBounds(InxD)
      End If
    Next
    InxA = InxA + 1   ' Step index into MDSArray to match Coords
    If InxA > InxMax Then
      Exit Do
    End If

    '' Output co-ordinates to show which elements caused increase in width
    'Debug.Print "(";
    'For InxD = 1 To DimMax - 1
    '  Debug.Print Coords(InxD) & ", ";
    'Next
    'Debug.Print Coords(DimMax) & ") ";

  Loop
  'Debug.Print

  ' Output header
  Debug.Print "Value for each element in MDSArray"
  Debug.Print "|";
  For InxD = 1 To DimMax - 1
    Debug.Print PadR("D" & CStr(InxD), ColWidthsNotLast(InxD)) & "|";
  Next
  Debug.Print "|";
  For InxWL = LBounds(DimMax) To UBounds(DimMax)
    Debug.Print PadR(CStr(InxWL), ColWidthsLast(InxWL)) & "|";
  Next
  Debug.Print

  ' Output data rows.
  ' One row for each value of each index for every dimension except last
  ' Left of row contains indices for dimensions other thsn last
  ' Right of row contains values for each index into last dimension
  ' Initialise Coords to indices for first entry in MDS array
  For InxC = 1 To DimMax
    Coords(InxC) = LBounds(InxC)
  Next
  InxA = 1
  Do While InxA <= InxMax
    Debug.Print "|";
    ' Output current index for dimensions except last
    For InxD = 1 To DimMax - 1
      Debug.Print PadR(Coords(InxD), ColWidthsNotLast(InxD)) & "|";
    Next
    Debug.Print "|";
    ' Output values for each index into last dimension
    Do While True
      Debug.Print PadR(MDSArray(InxA), ColWidthsLast(Coords(DimMax))) & "|";
      ' Step Coords to next entry
      For InxD = DimMax To 1 Step -1
        If Coords(InxD) < UBounds(InxD) Then
          Coords(InxD) = Coords(InxD) + 1
          Exit For
        Else
          Coords(InxD) = LBounds(InxD)
        End If
      Next
      InxA = InxA + 1   ' Step index into MDSArray to match Coords
      If InxA > InxMax Then
        Exit Do
      End If
      If Coords(DimMax) = LBounds(DimMax) Then
        ' Start of new row
        Debug.Print
        Exit Do
      End If
    Loop
  Loop
  Debug.Print

End Sub
Public Sub PutElements(ParamArray Params() As Variant)

  ' Saves one or more strings starting at a specified element within
  ' the multi-dimensional string array.

  ' This sub has two compulsory parameters.  The declaration uses a ParamArray
  ' to allow maximum flexibility in the type of those parameters.  Effectively,
  ' this sub has a declaration of:
  '   PutElements(ByRef Start() As xxxx, ByRef Values() as yyyy) or
  '   PutElements(ByRef Start() As xxxx, ByVal Values as yyyy) or
  '     where xxxx can be any of the integer types plus Variant or String.
  '       and yyyy can be any type that can be converted to a string plus
  '           Variant providing all the values within the Variant can be
  '           converted to strings.

  ' Start is a one-dimensional array with DimMax, integer elements.  If the
  ' type of the array is Variant or String, the element values must be integer
  ' or an integer held as a string. The bounds of the array are not important.
  ' A lower bound of one to match dimension one may be convenient but a lower
  ' bound of zero or some other value may be used if wished.

  ' If the MDS array has N dimensions, Start must contain N values each of
  ' which must be within the bounds for the corresponding dimension.  Together,
  ' the values within Start specify an element with the MDS array.

  ' Values can be a variable of any type that can be converted to a string.
  ' Alternately, Values can be a one-dimensional array containing one or more
  ' elements. If Values contains one element, the value of that element will be
  ' saved to element Start of the MDS array. If Values contains more than one
  ' element, the values of those elements will be saved to the MDS array
  ' starting at Start and continuing in the sequence defined at the top of this
  ' module until all values in Values have been saved or the last element of
  ' MDSArray has been reached.

  'Debug.Print "PutElements"

  If DimMax = 0 Then
    Debug.Assert False    'Not initialised
    Exit Sub
  End If

  Dim InxA As Long
  Dim InxS As Long
  Dim InxV As Long
  Dim LB As Long
  Dim Start() As Long
  Dim UB As Long

  LB = LBound(Params)
  UB = UBound(Params)

  If LB + 1 <> UB Then
    Debug.Assert False  ' There must be exactly two parameters
    Exit Sub
  End If

  If VarType(Params(LB)) < vbArray Then
    Debug.Assert False  ' First parameter (Start) must be an array
    Exit Sub
  End If

  ' Params(Params(LB)) contains values for Start.
  InxS = 1
  If UBound(Params(LB)) - LBound(Params(LB)) + 1 <> DimMax Then
    Debug.Assert False  ' Start must have one entry per dimension
    Exit Sub
  End If

  ReDim Start(1 To DimMax)

  For InxV = LBound(Params(LB)) To UBound(Params(LB))
    ' An error here indicates a value that cannot be converted to a Long
    Start(InxS) = Params(LB)(InxV)
    If Start(InxS) < LBounds(InxS) Or Start(InxS) > UBounds(InxS) Then
      Debug.Assert False  ' Index is outside range for dimension
      Exit Sub
    End If
    InxS = InxS + 1
  Next

  InxA = 1
  For InxS = 1 To DimMax
    InxA = InxA + (Start(InxS) - LBounds(InxS)) * DimOffs(InxS)
  Next

  '' Report conversion from coordinates to InxA
  'Debug.Print "(";
  'For InxS = 1 To DimMax - 1
  '  Debug.Print Start(InxS) & ", ";
  'Next
  'Debug.Print Start(DimMax) & ") -> " & InxA

  If VarType(Params(UB)) < vbArray Then
    ' Single value to be stored in element defined by Start
    'Debug.Assert False
    ' An error here indicates Params(UB) cannot be converted to a string
    MDSArray(InxA) = Params(UB)
  Else
    ' Array of values to be stored starting at element defined by Start
    'Debug.Assert False
    'Debug.Print "Params(UB) Bounds: " & LBound(Params(UB)) & " To " & UBound(Params(UB))
    For InxV = LBound(Params(UB)) To UBound(Params(UB))
      MDSArray(InxA) = Params(UB)(InxV)
      'Debug.Print Params(UB)(InxV) & " -> (" & InxA & ")"
      InxA = InxA + 1
      If InxA > InxMax Then
        ' Have reached end of MDSArray
        Exit For
      End If
    Next
  End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer has exceeded Stackoverflow's limit of 30,000 characters so I have split it into parts.  This is part 2.

This block of code is my test routines.  I recommend you try them.  If nothing else, they demonstrates how to use the class’s methods.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test1()

  Dim MyArray1 As New MultDimStrArray
  Dim MyArray2 As MultDimStrArray
  Dim MyArray3 As MultDimStrArray

  Dim Bounds1 As Variant
  Dim Bounds2() As String

  Set MyArray2 = New MultDimStrArray
  Set MyArray3 = New MultDimStrArray

  Bounds1 = Array("3 To 10", "2", 5)

  ReDim Bounds2(1 To 3)
  Bounds2(1) = "3 to 10"
  Bounds2(2) = "2"
  Bounds2(3) = "5"

  ' Error-free calls
  Call MyArray1.Initialise("3 to 10", "2")
  Call MyArray1.OutDiag
  Call MyArray2.Initialise(Bounds1)
  Call MyArray2.OutDiag
  Call MyArray3.Initialise(Bounds2)
  Call MyArray3.OutDiag
  Call MyArray1.Initialise("3 to 10", 2)
  Call MyArray1.OutDiag
  Call MyArray1.Initialise(2, "-5 to -2")
  Call MyArray1.OutDiag

  ' Calls that end in an error
  Call MyArray1.Initialise("3 to 10", "a")
  Call MyArray1.OutDiag
  Call MyArray1.Initialise("3 to 2")
  Call MyArray1.OutDiag
  Call MyArray1.Initialise("2to3")
  Call MyArray1.OutDiag
  Call MyArray1.Initialise(0)
  Call MyArray1.OutDiag
  Call MyArray1.Initialise(1.5)
  Call MyArray1.OutDiag
  Call MyArray1.Initialise("2 to ")
  Call MyArray1.OutDiag
  Call MyArray1.Initialise(" to 2")
  Call MyArray1.OutDiag

End Sub
Sub Test2()

  Dim InxD1 As Long
  Dim InxD2 As Long
  Dim InxD3 As Long
  Dim MyArray As New MultDimStrArray
  Dim Start As Variant
  Dim ValueCrnt As String
  Dim Values() As String

  Call MyArray.Initialise("3 to 5", 3)

  Call MyArray.PutElements(Array(3, 1), _
                            Array("Three-One", "Three-Two", "Three-Three", _
                                  "Four-One", "Four-Two", "Four-Three", _
                                  "Five-One", "Five-Two", "Five-Three"))

  Call MyArray.OutDiag

  ReDim Values(0 To 0)
  For InxD1 = 3 To 5
    For InxD2 = 1 To 3
      Start = Array(InxD1, InxD2)
      Values(0) = InxD1 & "." & InxD2
      Call MyArray.PutElements(Start, Values)
    Next
  Next

  Call MyArray.OutDiag

  For InxD1 = 3 To 5
    For InxD2 = 1 To 3
      Start = Array(InxD1, InxD2)
      ValueCrnt = InxD1 & "-" & InxD2
      Call MyArray.PutElements(Start, ValueCrnt)
    Next
  Next

  Call MyArray.OutDiag

  Call MyArray.Initialise("5 to 10", 3, "-3 to 4")

  Debug.Print
  ReDim Values(-3 To 4)
  For InxD1 = 10 To 5 Step -1
    For InxD2 = 1 To 3
      Start = Array(InxD1, InxD2, -3)
      For InxD3 = -3 To 4
        Values(InxD3) = InxD1 & "." & InxD2 & "." & InxD3
      Next
      Call MyArray.PutElements(Start, Values)
    Next
  Next

  Call MyArray.OutDiag

End Sub
Sub Test3()

  Dim InxD1 As Long
  Dim InxD2 As Long
  Dim InxV As Long
  Dim MyArray As New MultDimStrArray
  Dim Start As Variant
  Dim ValueCrnt As String
  Dim Values() As String

  Call MyArray.Initialise("3 to 5", 3)

  Call MyArray.PutElements(Array(3, 1), _
                            Array("Three-One", "Three-Two", "Three-Three", _
                                  "Four-One", "Four-Two", "Four-Three", _
                                  "Five-One", "Five-Two", "Five-Three"))

  Call MyArray.OutDiag

  ReDim Values(1 To 9)

  Call MyArray.GetElements(Array(3, 1), Values)

  Debug.Print
  For InxV = LBound(Values) To UBound(Values)
    Debug.Print """" & Values(InxV) & """  ";
  Next
  Debug.Print

  ReDim Values(1 To 3)

  Debug.Print
  For InxD1 = 3 To 5

    Call MyArray.GetElements(Array(InxD1, 1), Values)

    For InxV = LBound(Values) To UBound(Values)
      Debug.Print """" & Values(InxV) & """  ";
    Next
    Debug.Print

  Next

  ReDim Values(1 To 4)
  For InxV = LBound(Values) To UBound(Values)
    Values(InxV) = "Unchanged"
  Next

  Call MyArray.GetElements(Array(5, 1), Values)

  Debug.Print
  For InxV = LBound(Values) To UBound(Values)
    Debug.Print """" & Values(InxV) & """  ";
  Next
  Debug.Print

  Debug.Print
  For InxD1 = 3 To 5
    For InxD2 = 1 To 3
      Call MyArray.GetElements(Array(InxD1, InxD2), ValueCrnt)
      Debug.Print "(" & InxD1 & ", " & InxD2 & ") contains " & ValueCrnt
    Next
  Next

End Sub
```

Over the years, I have created subroutines and functions that perform useful tasks not provided by Excel’s standard subroutines and functions.  I use PERSONAL.XLSB as a library to hold all these macros.  This is one of those functions which is used by `OutDiag`.

```
Option Explicit
Public Function PadR(ByVal Str As String, ByVal PadLen As Long, _
                     Optional ByVal PadChr As String = " ") As String

  ' Pad Str with trailing PadChr to give a total length of PadLen
  ' If the length of Str exceeds PadLen, Str will not be truncated

  '   Nov15 Coded
  ' 15Sep16 Added PadChr so could pad with characters other than space

  If Len(Str) >= PadLen Then
    ' Do not truncate over length strings
    PadR = Str
  Else
    PadR = Left$(Str & String(PadLen, PadChr), PadLen)
  End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

**VBA arrays, Variants and Variant arrays**

This answer provides the background necessary to understand some of the code within the other answers and to understand why I rejected an alternative approach.

To declare simple variables, I write:

```
Dim A As Long
Dim B As String
Dim C As Boolean
Dim D As Integer
Dim E As Double
```

VBA has a selection of intrinsic data types that are not very different from those available with other languages.

VBA has another type:

Dim F As Variant

A Variant might be thought of as untyped or as a container.  If I write:

```
A = 5       ' OK because A is Long
A = "abc"   ' Will fail a n alphabetic string cannot be saved in a Long
A = "123"   ' OK because string "123" is automatically converted to integer 123
```

On the other hand, I can write the following without any failures:

```
F = 5
F = "abc"
F = True
F = 1.23
```

Each of these values will be held correctly.  F can be used in any expression for which its current value is appropriate:

```
F = 5
F = F + 2
F = "abc"
F = F & "def"
```

The above statements are all valid but

```
F = "abc"
F = F + 2
```

will fail because after setting F to "abc", it cannot be used in an arithmetic expression.

A Variant can also hold an Excel worksheet, a Word document or any Office object.  A Variant can also hold an array.  When a Variant holds an object or an array, the syntax is as though the Variant has become that object or array.  So:

```
F = Worksheets("Data”)
F.Range("A1") = "abc"
```

Above, F is now effectively a variable of type Worksheet and any of a Worksheet’s properties or methods can be accessed by F.  This was just to give a brief taste on the full scope of Variants; the remainder of this tutorial is limited to arrays.

I can “convert” a Variant to an array in one of two ways:

```
1) F = VBA.Array(1, "abc", True)
2) ReDim F(0 To 2)
```

VBA.Array is a function which returns a one-dimensional Variant array with lower bound 0 and enough elements to hold the supplied values.  I can also write `F = Array(1, "abc", True)`.  Function `Array` is the same as Function `VBA.Array` except the lower bound depends on the present and value of the `Option Base` command.

I only use function `Array` if I am going to use function `LBound` to determine the lower bound.  I do not fully understand what is and what is not effected by the `Option Base` command since it is not fully documented.  I have seen differences between different versions of different Microsoft products which I am sure are accidental.  I am confident a new Microsoft programmer has assumed an old product operates in a sensible manner when it does not.  I am very careful to specify both lower and upper bounds if I can.  If I cannot specify the lower bound, I check it.  I still use routines I wrote under Excel 2003.  I believe the lack of problems I encounter with old routines is because I avoid making assumptions about how Excel operates if it is not fully documented.

Returning to the tutorial, `ReDim F(0 To 2)` effectively converts F to an array with three elements..

All previous discussions have been about one-dimensional arrays.  Conventional multi-dimensional arrays are also possible:

```
Dim G(1 to 5) As Long
Dim H(1 to 5, 1 To 4) As String
Dim I(1 to 5, 1 To 4, 0 To 3) As Boolean
```

or

```
Dim G() As Long
Dim H() As String
Dim I() As Boolean
ReDim G(1 to 5)
ReDim H(1 to 5, 1 To 4)
ReDim I(1 to 5, 1 To 4, 0 To 3)
```

With the first block, the number and size of the dimensions are fixed at compile time.  With second block, the number and size of the dimensions are set at runtime and can be changed.

In either case, the syntax for access is:

```
G(n) = 3
H(n, m) = "abc"
I(n, m, o) = True
```

This type of multi-dimensional is inappropriate for your requirement.  Although the bounds can be changed at runtime, the number of dimensions cannot be changed within a ReDim statement, A Select statement would be need to select from a long list of pre-prepared ReDim statements with one for each possible number of dimensions.

The alternative is ragged or jagged arrays although without them being ragged.

Consider:

```
Dim F As Variant
ReDim F(0 To 2)
F(0) = VBA.Array(1, 2, 3)
F(1) = VBA.Array(4, 5, 6)
F(2) = VBA.Array(7, 8, 9)
```

I have made F into a three element array and have then made each element of F into an array.  To access the elements of the inner arrays, I write: F(n)(m) where both n and m can be 0, 1 or 2.

I can continue:

F(0)(0) = VBA.Array(10, 11, 12)

After this change, element F(0)(0)(0) has a value of 10 and F(0)(0)(1) has a value of 11.

I can continue this indefinitely.  I have read that VBA has a limit of 60 dimensions with conventional multi-dimensional arrays.  I have not tried but I cannot see why there would be any limit on the number of dimensions with this technique other than memory.

This technique appears to have the same limitation as regular multi-dimensional arrays.  I can write F(0)(0) or F(0)(0)(0) but I cannot change the depth of the simple variable at runtime.

There is also the problem that ReDim F(0)(0 To 2) is rejected by the compiler as invalid syntax.  That was why I used VBA.Array to convert F(0) to an array.

The solution is recursion.  Consider:

```
Call ReDimVar(F, "1 To 2", "3 To 4", "0 To 5")
```

ReDimVar can:

```
ReDim F(1 To 2)
Call ReDimVar(F(1), "3 To 4", "0 To 5") 
Call ReDimVar(F(2), "3 To 4", "0 To 5")
```

All this can be handled with simple loops.  I rejected this technique because recursion is slow and your question implies significant volumes of data and many dimensions.  However, to demonstrate that it would work, play with the following:

```
Sub TryMDVA()

  ' Demonstrate how to:
  '   1) Convert a Variant into a multi-dimension array
  '   2) Store values in every element of that multi-dimension array
  '   3) Extract values from every element of that multi-dimension array

  Dim Coords() As Long
  Dim ElementValue As String
  Dim InxB As Long             ' Index for both Bounds and Coords
  Dim InxD1 As Long
  Dim InxD2 As Long
  Dim InxD3 As Long
  Dim LwrBnds As Variant
  Dim MDVA As Variant
  Dim UppBnds As Variant

  LwrBnds = Array(1, 0, -3)
  UppBnds = Array(2, 5, 4)

  ReDim Bounds(LBound(LwrBnds) To UBound(LwrBnds))
  ReDim Coords(LBound(LwrBnds) To UBound(LwrBnds))

  Call FormatMDVA(MDVA, LwrBnds, UppBnds)

  Debug.Print "Results of formatting MDVA"
  Debug.Print "Bounds of MDVA are " & LBound(MDVA) & " to " & UBound(MDVA)
  Debug.Print "Bounds of MDVA(1) are " & LBound(MDVA(1)) & " to " & UBound(MDVA(1))
  Debug.Print "Bounds of MDVA(2) are " & LBound(MDVA(2)) & " to " & UBound(MDVA(2))
  Debug.Print "Bounds or MDVA(1)(0) are " & LBound(MDVA(1)(0)) & " to " & UBound(MDVA(1)(0))
  Debug.Print "Bounds or MDVA(2)(5) are " & LBound(MDVA(2)(5)) & " to " & UBound(MDVA(2)(5))

  ' Initialise Coords to lower bound of each dimension
  For InxB = LBound(LwrBnds) To UBound(LwrBnds)
    Coords(InxB) = LwrBnds(InxB)
  Next

  Do While True
    ' Build element value from coordinates
    ElementValue = Coords(LBound(Coords))
    For InxB = LBound(LwrBnds) + 1 To UBound(LwrBnds)
      ElementValue = ElementValue & "." & Coords(InxB)
    Next
    ' Store element value in element of MDVA specified by Coords
    Call PutElement(MDVA, Coords, ElementValue)
    ' Step Coords.  Think of Coords as a speedometer with each wheel marked
    ' with the available index values for a dimension. Starting on the right,
    ' check each wheel against the relevant ubound.  If it is less than the
    ' ubound, step it by 1. If it is the upper bound, reset it to the lower
    ' bound and try the next wheel to the left.  If the leftmost wheel is
    ' to be reset, Coords has been set to all possible values.
    For InxB = UBound(LwrBnds) To LBound(LwrBnds) Step -1
      If Coords(InxB) < UppBnds(InxB) Then
        Coords(InxB) = Coords(InxB) + 1
        Exit For
      Else
        If InxB = LBound(LwrBnds) Then
          Exit Do
        End If
        Coords(InxB) = LwrBnds(InxB)
      End If
    Next
  Loop

  Debug.Print "Example values from within MDVA"
  Debug.Print "MDVA(1)(0)(-3) = " & MDVA(1)(0)(-3)
  Debug.Print "MDVA(1)(0)(-2) = " & MDVA(1)(0)(-2)
  Debug.Print "MDVA(2)(3)(0) = " & MDVA(2)(3)(0)
  Debug.Print "MDVA(2)(5)(4) = " & MDVA(2)(5)(4)

  ' Initialise Coords to upper bound of each dimension
  For InxB = LBound(UppBnds) To UBound(UppBnds)
    Coords(InxB) = UppBnds(InxB)
  Next

  Debug.Print "List of all values in MDVA"
  Do While True
    ' Output value of element of MDVA identified by Coords
    Debug.Print "MDVA(" & Coords(LBound(UppBnds));
    For InxB = LBound(UppBnds) + 1 To UBound(UppBnds)
      Debug.Print ", " & Coords(InxB);
    Next
    Debug.Print ") = """ & GetElement(MDVA, Coords) & """"

    ' Set next value of Coords.  Similar to code block in PutElement
    ' but in the opposite direction
    For InxB = UBound(LwrBnds) To LBound(LwrBnds) Step -1
      If Coords(InxB) > LwrBnds(InxB) Then
        Coords(InxB) = Coords(InxB) - 1
        Exit For
      Else
        If InxB = LBound(LwrBnds) Then
          Exit Do
        End If
        Coords(InxB) = UppBnds(InxB)
      End If
    Next
  Loop

End Sub
Sub FormatMDVA(ByRef MDVA As Variant, LwrBnds As Variant, UppBnds As Variant)

  ' Size MDVA according to the bounds in the first elements of LwrBnds and
  ' UppBnds. If there are further elements in LwrBnds and UppBnds, call
  ' FormatMDVA to format every element of MDVA according to the remaining
  ' elements.

  Dim InxB As Long
  Dim InxM As Long
  Dim LB As Long
  Dim SubLwrBnds As Variant
  Dim SubUppBnds As Variant

  LB = LBound(LwrBnds)

  ReDim MDVA(LwrBnds(LB) To UppBnds(LB))

  If LBound(LwrBnds) = UBound(LwrBnds) Then
    ' All bounds applied
  Else
    ' Another dimension to format
    ReDim SubLwrBnds(LB + 1 To UBound(LwrBnds))
    ReDim SubUppBnds(LB + 1 To UBound(UppBnds))
    ' Copy remaining bounds to new arrays
    For InxB = LB + 1 To UBound(LwrBnds)
      SubLwrBnds(InxB) = LwrBnds(InxB)
      SubUppBnds(InxB) = UppBnds(InxB)
    Next

    For InxM = LwrBnds(LB) To UppBnds(LB)
      Call FormatMDVA(MDVA(InxM), SubLwrBnds, SubUppBnds)
    Next
  End If

End Sub
Function GetElement(ByRef MDVA As Variant, ByRef Coords() As Long) As Variant

  ' Return the value of the element of MDVA identified by Coords

  Dim InxC As Long
  Dim LB As Long
  Dim SubCoords() As Long

  LB = LBound(Coords)

  If LB = UBound(Coords) Then
    ' Have reached innermost array
    GetElement = MDVA(Coords(LB))
  Else
    ' At least one more nested array
    ReDim SubCoords(LB + 1 To UBound(Coords))
    For InxC = LB + 1 To UBound(Coords)
      SubCoords(InxC) = Coords(InxC)
    Next
    GetElement = GetElement(MDVA(Coords(LB)), SubCoords)
  End If
End Function
Sub PutElement(ByRef MDVA As Variant, ByRef Coords() As Long, _
               ElementValue As Variant)

  ' Save the value of ElementValue in the element of MDVA identified by Coords

  Dim InxC As Long
  Dim LB As Long
  Dim SubCoords() As Long

  LB = LBound(Coords)

  If LB = UBound(Coords) Then
    ' Have reached innermost array
    MDVA(Coords(LB)) = ElementValue
  Else
    ' At least one more nested array
    ReDim SubCoords(LB + 1 To UBound(Coords))
    For InxC = LB + 1 To UBound(Coords)
      SubCoords(InxC) = Coords(InxC)
    Next
    Call PutElement(MDVA(Coords(LB)), SubCoords, ElementValue)
  End If
End Sub
```